# Change VertexSize in a big graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to understand when `VertexSize` property works on the graph. I experimented with a small number of nodes (about 100) and try to change the size of only 5 vertices out of 100 and it worked.  However, when you take a graph with a large number of nodes (for example 1000 nodes and 2000 edges - `RandomGraph[{1000,2000}]` and try to change the size of 10 vertices, `VertexSize` does not seem to work. I even tried with affixing the property to the vertex by using `Property` but could not get to work.

So, after how many nodes does `VertexSize` does not work? Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following work in version 9:

```
RandomGraph[{1000, 2000}, 
 VertexSize -> Join[{_ -> Scaled[.01]}, Thread[Range[10] -> Scaled[.04]]]]
```

[image]

```
RandomGraph[{1000, 2000}, 
 VertexSize -> Join[{_ -> 3}, Thread[Range[10] -> 10]]]
```

[image]

**Update:** For versions 11+ , as shown in halmir's answer, explicit setting of  `GraphStyle` or `VertexShapeFunction`  options gives the desired result. In particular, using the option `GraphStyle` with any value, e.g.

```
GraphStyle -> {}
GraphStyle- > "BasicBlue"
GraphStyle-> blah
```

with the same `VertexSize` settings as in the examples above gives

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on Mathematica 11 @kglr. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: @no-one, it doesn't work in version 11 as is. If we  the `GraphStyle` option, (regardless of the option value used)  it works in version 11 too.

Answer (score 3):

You could specify `VertexShapeFunction` or set `GraphStyle -> "Default"`

```
RandomGraph[{1000, 2000}, VertexSize -> 6, VertexShapeFunction -> "Circle"]

RandomGraph[{1000, 2000}, VertexSize -> 5, GraphStyle -> "Default" ]
```

Comment: Could you make `GraphElementData["GraphStyle"]` list `"Default"` as well?

Comment: What is the `GraphStyle` that Mathematica uses for large graphs?  It is not `"LargeGraph"` or `"LargeNetwork"`, and with these styles the rendering is not as fast as with the automatically chosen style.

Comment: It's "LargeNetworkDefault"